# How to Set Sqllite Result Set to insert Only Distinct Value in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, insert-update, distinct-values

i am newbie in iOS and also newbie in sqllite database so please help me for my Question. I want to Insert Only Distinct Value in sqllite Table, like as Here i Insert Value in to My Table

```
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
const char *dbpath = [_databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_myDatabase) == SQLITE_OK) {

    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"INSERT INTO ALLREADTABLE (PostId, PostTitle, ImageLink, ShortDescription,Category,PostDate) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",
                           post_id, cell.headLabel.text, image,self.shortDiscription,cell.categoryLabel.text,cell.timeLabel.text];

    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(_myDatabase, insert_stmt,
                       -1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSString *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Value Added %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ ",post_id, cell.headLabel.text, image,self.shortDiscription,cell.categoryLabel.text,cell.timeLabel.text];
        NSLog(@"String %@",string);
    } else
    {
       NSLog(@"Failed to add contact");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(_myDatabase);
}
```

Now i want when i insert same value into table then i want old value are deleted and new value are inserted in to my table.How it is Possible Please Give me Solution for it.

Comment: change **INSERT**  into **INSERT OR REPLACE**

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik then it add only one row value in to table for same value?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i try it when i add same value tree times and Fetch then i got same value three times i want to insert same value in one time if i select same value n times then insert only one time in table.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik it is not working for me please help me.

Comment: INSERT OR REPLACE condition is working like , if already the same value is available it automatically replace the same value otherwise it insert the data

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i write a query like as `NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ALLREADTABLE (PostId, PostTitle, ImageLink, ShortDescription,Category,PostDate) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",
                               post_id, cell.headLabel.text, image,self.shortDiscription,cell.categoryLabel.text,cell.timeLabel.text];` but it is not working for me.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik here my Table creation like as `"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ALLREADTABLE (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, PostId TEXT , PostTitle TEXT, ImageLink TEXT, ShortDescription TEXT,Category TEXT,PostDate TEXT,Bookmark INTEGER DEFAULT 0)"` so here my ID is auto increment so it is not replace .it is right or not?